# Isaiah 40:12 and its meaning

Tags: isaiah

What is the meaning of "knows the weight of earth" in Isaiah 40:12, or as some translations render it, "comprehended the dust of the earth"? I mean does that that we today know the weight of the earth and know everything about it so we, "comprehended the earth" shatters the uniquenes of God?

Sorry for my English, it is my second language.

Comment: No apology necessary.  we are all here to help.

Answer (score 3):

Who hath measured in the hollow of his hand the waters? And the heavens by a span hath meted out, And comprehended in a measure the dust of the earth, And hath weighed in scales the mountains, And the hills in a balance? Who hath meted out the Spirit of Jehovah, And, being His counsellor, doth teach Him! With whom consulted He, That he causeth Him to understand? And teacheth Him in the path of judgment, And teacheth Him knowledge? And the way of understanding causeth Him to know? - Isaiah 40:12-14

The passage is about God's unique pre-eminence.

The language is figurative; "The water of the earth were measured in His hand".

The question is expecting a negative response; Who has shown, taught, or helped God do these things?

The answer is; No one.

Comment: Yes, agreed. +1. Job is being put in his place. These are not hypothetical questions. They demand the answer that you have given : none but ***God*** knows such things as these !

Comment: I think the OP a makes a valid point. Today scientists claim to have the answers to these questions. Does it therefore nullify God’s uniqueness? Or if NigelJ is correct then it would follow that science today is incorrect

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I mean.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo If, by scientists today, you refer to a body of educated professionals positing entirely naturalistic origins of all that there is without need of an ultimate supernatural source then, yes, scientists today are wrong.  Everything is held together by the word of His power and human knowledge cannot comprehend that.